# SQL: How to get the row when max is on more than 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a table named **employee**:

```
create table employee (
   employee_id bigint not null primary key, 
   first_name varchar(50) not null, 
   middle_name varchar(50) null, 
   last_name varchar(50) not null
)
```

I have a table named **eligibility**. It has a FK to employee table. It has a unique key comprise of 3 columns: employee_id + effective_date + sequence_number.

```
create table eligibility (
   eligibility_id bigint not null primary key,
   employee_id bigint not null foreign key references employee (employee_id), 
   effective_date date not null,
   sequence_number int not null,
   value varchar(20) not null,
   constraint UK_eligibility unique (employee_id, effective_date, sequence_number)
)
```

I have 1 row in **employee** table with employee_id = 1001:

```
insert into employee (employee_id, first_name, middle_name, last_name) values (1001, 'A', 'B', 'C')
```

I have 4 rows in **eligibility** table for the same employee_id:

```
insert into eligibility (eligibility_id, employee_id, effective_date, sequence_number, value) values (1, 1001, '2016-04-13', 1, 'NS')
insert into eligibility (eligibility_id, employee_id, effective_date, sequence_number, value) values (2, 1001, '2016-05-25', 1, 'EX')
insert into eligibility (eligibility_id, employee_id, effective_date, sequence_number, value) values (3, 1001, '2016-05-25', 2, 'VR')
insert into eligibility (eligibility_id, employee_id, effective_date, sequence_number, value) values (4, 1001, '2016-06-05', 1, 'LS')
```

From the eligibility table, for a given date I want to get the row with the max (effective_date + sequence_number) combination which is less than or equal to that given date.

***Examples:*** 
For `2016-04-30` date I would want the row with eligibility_id = 1.
For `2016-05-30` date I would want the row with eligibility_id = 3.
For `2016-06-30` date I would want the row with eligibility_id = 4.

I have wrote the query to get the desired results. This is the query for `2016-05-30` date:

```
select * from eligibility e 
where 
    e.effective_date = (select max(e1.effective_date) 
                            from eligibility e1 
                            where e1.employee_id = e.employee_id and 
                                e1.effective_date <= '2016-05-30') AND 
    e.sequence_number = (select max(e2.sequence_number)
                            from eligibility e2 
                            where e2.employee_id = e.employee_id and 
                                e2.effective_date = e.effective_date)
```

The query is ok but I want to try write it in some different way to get the same results. What other way you would recommend?

Comment: What characteristics of your query do you hope to improve by rewriting it?  "some different way to get the same results" affords infinitely many possibilities.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I dont like the 2 times I am using eligibility table in the where clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm, I would use `row_number()`:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by employee_id order by effective_date desc, sequence_number desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from eligibility e
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like TOP-1 with ties:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM eligibility e
WHERE e.effective_date <= '2016-05-30'
ORDER BY e.effective_date DESC, sequence_number DESC
```